# Mice function in R freezing

Tags: r, missing-data, mice

I am attempting to impute my data for missing values using the `mice` function (from the [mice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html) package) in R. However everytime I run the function it freezes or lags.

I have tried running it over night, and it still does not finish. I am working with 17000 observations across 32 variables.  I can't even stop the function after it starts, I have to force quit the program.

Here is my code:

```
imputed.data = mice(data, m = 1, diagnostics = F)
```

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, mice is relatively slow (especially for big datasets) and unparallellizable (makes sense because of the type of algorithm). In previous examples I've been able to speed it up by specifying a `predictorMatrix` so not every variable is used to predict every other variable (simplifies the intermediate model fitting). However, depending on your variables and their (known or unknown) relations, this may be unwanted.

To ensure that nothing else is the matter, you may want to run `mice` on a smaller subset of you data with relatively little data missing (e.g. 200 rows with at most 5% missing data), or run it on a simulation dataset.

Comment: I tried running it on a subset of the data, only a 100 rows and I still experience the same issue.

Comment: So how much missing data do you have? And are a lot of the columns categorical data with many levels?

Comment: In total there about 35000 missing values.  Several of the columns are categorical, but I converted them from numeric to factor.

Comment: I still suspect that the multiple category factors could be the culprits (at least in part), because they will require a polytomous regression each time _and_ increase the number of variables used to predict the other columns. Can you run the example in `?mice`: `imp <- mice(nhanes)`? This is a smaller example with known results...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.  It's running, but I'm not sure if it will just freeze again or its actually working.

Comment: The `nhanes` example took only seconds on my 2 year old portable... you probably need to look into that (latest version of R / mice / ...)?

Comment: I have the most up to date versions and reinstalled them both to verify.